# Unterminated JSX contents

Tags: meteor, reactjs

In a meteor app, I am trying to render a login form using React.

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div class="login-card">
            <h1>Log-in</h1><br>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login" />
            </form>

            <a class="login-help" href="#">Register</a>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But metor is unable to compile the above jsx file and says .

```
While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
   client/loginForm.jsx:15:8: Unterminated JSX contents (15:8)
```

What can be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to close `br` element, in react always use selft close tags, and also dont use `class` use `className` instead

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="login-card">
            <h1>Log-in</h1><br/> // Close br
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" name="login" className="login login-submit" value="login" />
            </form>

            <a className="login-help" href="#">Register</a>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Login extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div class="login-card">
            <h1>Log-in</h1><br></br>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" />
                <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
                <input type="submit" name="login" class="login login-submit" value="login" />
            </form>

            <a class="login-help" href="#">Register</a>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Close the br tag